# Scraping info with BS4

Tags: beautifulsoup

I need to extrat the rating for each sku. IN this case is "4,0"

```
<span class="stamped-badge" data-rating="4.0" data-lang="es" aria-label="Rated 4,0 out of 5 stars">
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data=soup.find_all("span",class_="stamped-badge")

lst=[ i['data-rating'] for i in data]
```

Output:

```
['4.0',...]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you extracting each rating in a `for` loop, then you can use [`select_one()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=select#css-selectors) that accepts `CSS` selectors, and call for data-rating attribute (*`CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)*):

```py
soup.select_one('.stamped-badge')['data-rating']

# or iterating over container with needed data
for result in soup.select('css_selector'):
    rating = result.select_one('.stamped-badge')['data-rating']
```

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<span class="stamped-badge" data-rating="4.0" data-lang="es" aria-label="Rated 4,0 out of 5 stars">
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

rating = soup.select_one('.stamped-badge')['data-rating']
print(rating)

# 4.0
```